# Norm of a bounded and linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space and $x\in X ~,~f\in X^*$. I do not know why is There a sequence $\{x_i\}\subset X_{||.||\leq 1}$ such that $||f||=\lim|f(x_i)|$.

Please help me

Comment: You may want to add the requirement that $\|x_i\| = 1$. Otherwise (for $f \ne 0$), take any $x$ with $f(x) \ne 0$ and scale it appropriately.

Comment: Since $f$ is from the dual, we know that it is bounded and hence continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the definition of the norm in $X^*$?

Comment: I know that the definition of the norm in $X^*$, but I can not understand the relation between them.

Comment: The next step is to use the definition of the $\sup$ in the norm.

Comment: Please write the details

Comment: No, I won't do that for you -- you want to learn it ;) Do you know the definition of the $\sup$ (and its consequences)?

Comment: I think that for every $n> 0$ , there is $x_n\in X$ such that $||f||-\frac{1}{n}\leq |f(x_n)|\leq ||f||+\frac{1}{n}$. then when $n\to \infty$ we have $||f||=\lim |f(x_n)|$. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Note that you even have $|f(x_n)| \le \|f\|$ by definition of the norm.

Comment: Can one say that there is $x\in X$ such that $||f||=|f(x)|$?

Comment: No, not in general. But this is a different question...